# Passing array as props changes type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following;

```
export default function World() {
  const { backgroundTiles } = typedLevelData[`level_1`];
  console.log(Array.isArray(backgroundTiles));

  return (
    <Background {...backgroundTiles}/>
  )
}
```

As I'd expect, the console log returns true. However, in the Background component, attempting to call forEach returns a TypeError, stating that background.forEach is not a function.

```
export default function Background(backgroundTiles : BackgroundTile[]) {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current!;
    const ctx2d = canvas.getContext('2d')!;
    ctx2d?.clearRect(0, 0, 1200, 600);
    console.log(Array.isArray(backgroundTiles));

    backgroundTiles.forEach(async ({tileType, positions}) => {
      const image = await getImageByTileType[tileType];
      positions.forEach(([x, y]) => {
        ctx2d.drawImage(image, x, y);
      })
    })
  }, [backgroundTiles])

  return (
    <canvas
      className={styles.canvas}
      ref={canvasRef}
      height={600}
      width={1200}
    />
  )
}
```

Edit: BackgroundTile:

```
export interface BackgroundTile {
  tileType: TileTypes,
  passable: boolean,
  positions: number[][]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to spread an array into an object.

It just iterates the array as if it was an object, and adds properties on the fly, here is an example

```
const arr = ['a','b','c']
{...arr} === {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"} // something similar goes to your component.
```

So the solution is - just pass a named prop to Background (this is preferable option)

```
<Background backgroundTiles={backgroundTiles}/>
```

or destruct the whole object with backgroundTiles

```
<Background {...typedLevelData[`level_1`]}/>
```

But also don't forget to destruct it in the Background Component,

```
export default function Background({backgroundTiles} : {backgroundTiles:BackgroundTile[]}) {
```

because first argument that a component receives (props) is an object

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how backgroundTiles looks like, but you better try passing it like that to your component:

```
export default function World() {
  const { backgroundTiles } = typedLevelData[`level_1`];
  console.log(Array.isArray(backgroundTiles));

  return (
    <Background backgroundTiles={backgroundTiles}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: It's simply an array of Objects. It seems fairly strange to me, as it should be quite simple.